# How do I append a filename when doing a move-item

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

Separate all the files in C:\Users\jjudi\Documents\HomeWork\Sort into two folders: C:\Users\jjudi\Documents\HomeWork\Sort\new and C:\Users\jjudi\Documents\HomeWork\Sort\file. If the file name contains new, move
this file to the new_backup folder; file names that contain file should be moved to file_backup. For all files that are moved, you should append “_backup” to each of the file names.

```
 $files = Get-ChildItem 'C:\Users\jjudi\Documents\HomeWork\Sort' -Recurse | where {!$_.PsIsContainer}

 $targetnew = 'C:\Users\jjudi\Documents\HomeWork\Sort\new'
 foreach ($file in $files)
{
   $files.Name
   $Dirnew = $targetnew

   if($file -like 'new*')
     {
       
        $file | Move-Item -Destination $Dirnew + $file.BaseName + '_backup' -Force
        
     }


 }
```

I have been able to sort the files fine but unable to add _backup at the end of the files.

Comment: I suspect your target path is invalid. It might miss a backslash between `$Dirnew` and `$file.BaseName`. You can use `Join-Path` to create a valid path for your target file.

Comment: Doubled check file path it is correct, and wouldnt the move create a valid file path?

Comment: Olaf is correct based on your code. You are not adding the additional backslash. Example file will be called `NewTest.docx` is trying to go into `C:\Users\jjudi\Documents\HomeWork\Sort\newNewTest_backup`.

Comment: Your right thank you so much!